# CDC Fails due to Implicit Conversion ... how to find it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, implicit-conversion, cdc, change-data-capture

I'm working at a client and their CDC is failing due to an Implicit Conversion. The problem is that I can't find the exact statement that is doing the conversion.

I've tried using Pinal Dave's script (https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/01/29/find-queries-implict-conversion-sql-server-interview-question-week-107/) but none of the conversions from that list match the time and types that are in the CDC error.

Does anyone have more information on how I can resolve this?

Comment: Please add relevant code to your question and an error message, if any.

Comment: I can't add too much as I'm bound by confidentiality agreements. I can say this however:

SELECT * FROM sys.dm_cdc_errors

Produces these two rows
-- Implicit conversion from data type varchar to binary is not allowed .... 
-- Failed to insert rows into Change Data Capture change tables. Refer to previous errors in the current session to identify. 

Problem is I can't find the query which is attempting the implicit conversion

Comment: Is it possible to start an extended events session for that would to capture the statement?

Comment: @RodneyEllis Do you obtain records for this captured instance `sys.sp_cdc_get_ddl_history [your_captured_instance_name]` or querying `[cdc].[ddl_history]` ?

Comment: @snr - am getting the errors from : SELECT * FROM sys.dm_cdc_errors;

Comment: @BenThul - Am trying to set that up now, but am unsure of the events and fields to track. are you able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: I've used the session (or variations on it) listed here to pretty good success: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/08/what-queries-are-failing-in-my-sql-server/

Comment: cheers @BenThul that's a great article by Kendra. I was able to get this from the xEvent: [ sql_text - sys.sp_MScdc_capture_job]
I was hoping for more though. Am still at a loss   :'(

Comment: Ugh... unfortunate. Also captured is the tsql stack. Are you able to use those handles to find anything?

Comment: nothing that I can make sense of @benthul ... 4 lines of this: <frames><frame level='1' handle='0x03003500C9367549DA530A015BA7000...'

Comment: Sure. Those handles are (iirc) plan handles and you should be able to query sys.dm_exec_cached_plans for them. Alternatively (and perhaps in addition to), you can turn on event correlation on in your session and add something like sql_statement as an event. A word of caution though - make sure to add some sort of filter on the whole session so it doesn't collect *lots* of data. Filtering on something like the server_principal (i.e. the login) should work.

Comment: Firstly thanks @benthul for your awesome help on this. really appreciated. 
I've been trying to get the cached plan, but according to this link, inserts aren't cached (the original poster got into a little spat with Johnathan Kehayias) 
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cb597539-ea44-4bf3-863d-3a93f2c6d34c/event-session-does-not-pick-up-insert-statement?forum=sqldatabaseengine    
I'll try your second suggestion there of turning on event correlation.